# Cutting Shapes Into Another

Tags: modifiers, knife-tool

I'd like to cut a complex pattern into another shape, to produce a square shape with holes of the pattern. However the knife project in both new and older versions of Blender either fails to work at all, or works quite badly; manually extruded and filling in the missing faces also seems like it would take forever, considering the amount of vertices in the pattern.
Does anyone know a quick way to cut the patterns I have into a square solid?
[image]

Here is a mega link to the file:
https://mega.nz/file/nBclFI7C#NU-CMMXmpGEs3KdE0IYdYo9GF_zXRLabwb6hya_GWwM

Answer (score 1):

You can use booleans to do that.

First **select your curve** and **right click**>**convert to**>**mesh** (you can select a specific shape by hovering the mouse over it and hitting the "L" key  which selects everything connected)
[image]

Fill in the mesh, **with the everything selected, press the "F" key**. To create one big face.
[image]

extrude the geometry to thicken it up. **Edit Mode > E to extrude**

[image]

You can than use that shape as a cutter by placing it through the wall or object you want to cut through. **Selecting your cutter shape first** > **Shift click target object** (the one your cutting through), and than CTRL + the "-" sign *(on the NUM PAD)*

[image]